# How to make a delay after not hover on submenu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem with menu delay. I can't add delay when I not hover on submenu. What can I change to delay the submenu for 1 second when I not hover on it. I have to delete this delay when I hover on main menu.

better explenation:

When you hover the main menu items, the delay of the first item keeps the menu item open, while the mouse is already on the second menu item. See gif below.

How will I be able to fix this? Keeping the delay, but when another menu is open, hiding the menu item instantly.
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4UO6.gif)

structure of html (compressed for better view):

```
<div>
<ul class="menu_type_top">
<li><a href="#">Hello</a><li/>
<li><a href="#">hi</a>
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
<li><a href="#">hi</a></li>
</ul>

<li/>
<li><a href="#">ok</a><li/>

</ul>
</div>
```

Code in javascirpt to correct:

```
    $('ul.menu_type_top > li').on('mouseover', function(e){
            var ulObj = $(this).find("ul:first");
            console.log(ulObj);
            ulObj.show();
            var menu_height = ulObj[0].clientHeight + 300;
            $('ul.menu_type_top').css({ height: menu_height });//pokazanie podmenu bo warstwa jest w divie gdzie overflow: hidden
    
            
        }).on('mouseout', function(e){
             $(this).find("ul:first").hide();           
            $('ul.menu_type_top').css({ height: 40 });//powrót do normalnej wysokości menu
        });
        
        $('ul.menu_type_top li li').on('mouseover',function(e){
            if($(this).has('ul').length) {
                
            }
            
            $('ul:first',this).show();
        }).on('mouseout',function(e){
            
            $('ul:first', this).hide();
        });
```

Comment: Are you trying to introduce a delay in hiding the element while calling `.hide()`?  If so try setTimeout like `setTimeout( function(){ ulObj.hide(); }, 2000);`

Comment: Ok it is good but when I hover on main menu that mean menu-type-top from submenu(Menu in menu) it still has the delay. It has to reset the time when I mouseover on main menu from deep menu (Menu in menu)

Comment: @RPDP do you know how to do that?

Comment: I am not able to understand the requirement you are trying to achieve. To provide clarity can you post a working sample with the issue in jsfiddle.net  (or) an image(gif) which shows the behavior you are trying to build.

Comment: when You click on "problem" in my answer you will see the gif problem

Comment: To prevent stacking of submenus when you move along the main menu, before showing the submenu, call .hide() on all submenus like `$("ul:first").hide()`  and then show the specific submenu you want to show. 
This way you hide any open submenus before showing a new one.

Comment: Also there are better ways to create the submenu and topnav with just css alone.. To start with check  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_subnav.asp

Comment: Maybe you are genius I have written this in CSS, but the class menu_type_top has overflow:hidden, so my :hover on the menu  do nothing. I have to add height:300 px as you can see in my JQuery code (when I add height in  CSS transition-delay does NOT work). The menu is sliding in left and right because there are a lot of  "li". So I write this in Jquery, but when I use $("ul:first").hide() it will not work cause simply reason that menu in menu in menu will close beause there is a lot of submenus in one menu. I think about this problem for one week . Do you have any idea to solve this in CSS?